# Map of objects sharing characteristics

Tags: java, hash-map

### What I'm trying to achieve

From a list of lists of elements (one element can be in multiple lists, but only once in each list), I want to generate a map whose keys are each elements and the values are the collection of elements that appear at least once with the key in the first lists.

### Example

This is the input :

```
List<List<String>> input = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("calculating", "label", "farm", "anger", "able", "aboriginal"),
    Arrays.asList("injure", "label", "anger", "teeny-tiny", "able", "mindless", "teen"),
    Arrays.asList("injure", "calculating", "teeny-tiny", "mindless", "aboriginal")
);
```

I simplified the problem by using Strings but the elements could be any object. Please notice that:

- some words appear in multiple lists
- the list don't have any duplicates

The expected output should look like this:

```
{
     able=[teeny-tiny, farm, calculating, aboriginal, label, mindless, anger, injure, teen],
     teeny-tiny=[able, calculating, aboriginal, label, mindless, anger, injure, teen],
     farm=[able, calculating, aboriginal, label, anger],
     calculating=[able, teeny-tiny, farm, aboriginal, label, mindless, anger, injure],
     aboriginal=[able, teeny-tiny, farm, calculating, label, mindless, anger, injure],
     label=[able, teeny-tiny, farm, calculating, aboriginal, mindless, anger, injure, teen],
     mindless=[able, teeny-tiny, calculating, aboriginal, label, anger, injure, teen],
     anger=[able, teeny-tiny, farm, calculating, aboriginal, label, mindless, injure],
     injure=[able, teeny-tiny, calculating, aboriginal, label, mindless, anger]
}
```

So for example you see that the list associated with the value `farm` contains the value `calculating` because those two words were together in the first list of the input.

Also note that the resulting collections should not have duplicates: `label` and `able` are together in the first *and* second lists of the input, but the list associated to the key `able` (resp. `label`) in the result contains only one `label` (resp. `able`).

This is just an example. For my real problem, the input would not contain 3 lists of 5 or 6 elements, but a few thousand lists with hundreds of elements.

### The language

I'm implementing this in Java.

### My solution

This is what I could come up with and I'd like you to review:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (List<String> values : input.values()) {
    for (String str : values) {
        Set<String> l = result.getOrDefault(str, new HashSet<>());
        l.addAll(values);
        l.remove(str);
        result.put(str, l);
    }
}
```

### What I am going to use that for

It represents a simplification of a part of a problem I'm working with. I want to detect objects that are similar, but fully comparing two objects is computationally expensive. But I have a cheap way of grouping objects by characteristic. I want to use those characteristics to compare only objects that are potential matches.

For example, notice that, in the input of my example above, all the words of the first list  contain an `a`, all the words of the second list contain a `e` and an `i` for the third list. With the resulting map, I will be able to tell, for each of the keys, the list of words sharing one of those vowels. That way, I can avoid comparing `farm` and `teen` because they have nothing in common.

Comment: Welcome to code review. What are you using the map for? What is the language you are using. We could provide a better review with more code and more information.

Comment: (For your example, better have sets in `result` look widely different - choose none-too-common characters, consonants?)

Comment: I would have loved to vote to re-open this question. I would have much preferred to be presented the code where these `Map`s are used; one of my doubts: why not use this information "on the fly" instead of putting it into a map from keys to sets of related items? "In order to give good advice, we need to see real, concrete code, and understand the context in which the code is used."

Comment: Code Review does not do well with simplifications. Please take a look at our [FAQ on asking question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Comment: I think closing this question is unduly harsh. However I suggest you wrap your solution code in a a method and class. Add a test case based on your data and expected results and appeal the closure. On Code Review do not worry about posting 'too much code'.